# Сделать join таблицы в зависимости от значения

Tags: sql, postgresql

Недостаточно опытен в sql что бы оценить принятно и можно ли так делать.
Есть таблица в которой содержаться колонки code и type. В зависимости от того какого значения type хочу приджоинить таблицу из которой по коду получаю имя, и всё это в sql. Напрашивается конечно сделать подзапрос по результатам которого в if выбирать какой джоин делать, но может есть более адекватный вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT main.field, 
       CASE main.type
       WHEN 1 THEN slave1.field
       WHEN 2 THEN slave2.field
       ELSE NULL
       END slave_field

FROM      main
LEFT JOIN slave1 ON main.id = slave1.main_id
LEFT JOIN slave2 ON main.id = slave2.main_id

;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT main.code,
       desc1.description
FROM   main
       JOIN desc1 ON main.code = desc1.code
WHERE  main.type = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT main.code,
       desc2.description
FROM   main
       JOIN desc2 ON main.code = desc2.code
WHERE  main.type = 2;
```

А если хочется развлечься, то можно еще в сторону [наследования](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/ddl-inherit.html) посмотреть. Если таблицы-справочники отнаследовать от общего родителя, можно будет просто соединяться с родителем и запрос сам выберет все, что нужно, из дочерних таблиц.